# firebase realtime database undefined function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve from a realtime db I started by init the app with the configuration like so

```
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {getDatabase} from 'firebase/database';
let config = {
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
...
};
const app = initializeApp(config);
const database = getDatabase(app);
```

then when I try using the `database` variable it crashes

```
  componentDidMount() {
    database
      .ref(`master/tickets`)
      .once('value', snapshot => {
        var obj = snapshot.val();
        console.log('obj :', obj);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

I also have tried firebase.database.ref() it shows error cannot find variable firebase
What I am doing wrong? It was working fine in previous builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Web SDK underwent major breaking changes with the update to V9.0.0.

Please see the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) for details on how to modify older patterns to the new API.

```js
import { ref, get } from "firebase/database";
import { database } from "...";

/* ... */

componentDidMount() {
  get(ref(database, 'master/tickets'))
    .then(snapshot => {
      const obj = snapshot.val();
      console.log('obj :', obj);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: how do i export database from the config file?

Comment: @usfslk just add `export` at the front of it, so `export const database = getDatabase(app);`